# "MAN stack" how to access a local mongoDB database in angular app.,(no server,complete client side app.)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean

I have set up a mongoDB databse with lot of data stored among a lot of  collections, reside, in a 'data' folder inside my node app folder it self. 
I needed to create a front end to the database,with CRUD features using angular.I used node,and mongoose to set up database on my disk.I have no intention to upload the DB to a cloud at this point, so i guess, i don't need express,and $http service of angular.
 My question is this **How can i able to get access the mongoose query's from within different angular controllers. ?** Is there any services that i can use out of the box, as a dependency ,for the task.

alonge: In my mongoose model folder(in my case angular model itself), i've got a db.js file.This file contain all the mongoose queries that i need
to do with my front end(angular view:html file,with ton of partials). You can see, i need to somehow require and use this db.js file inside my angular controller.i don't know how to write the service that would do it though.I wonder 
"angoose" https://www.npmjs.com/package/angoose  Does it do the same thing..

ps 1: I have a plan to make this app a complete desktop app,using nw.js.

ps 2: i am relatively new to angular.js,.

Comment: I'm unsure thats possible with just angular, but if you use nw.js then you will have node and it's modules for the business layer

Comment: is angoose https://www.npmjs.com/package/angoose would do it..?

Comment: Okay..,how can i import db.js file into angular (which has got all my necessary mongoose query operations). Making a service, which uses this db.js  file, is what i'm thinking. So actually how to do this..?

Comment: @SijoPGeorge please [edit] the question and update the information rather than leaving it in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [NW.js docs](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Getting%20Started/) **Example 3** notes that you can use node function `require` for loading modules like so: `var mongoose = require('mongoose');`.

The caveat being that you may need to recompile the `mongoose` module with `nw-gyp` to make it work with NW.js.

Comment: How is angular going to communicate with node without making http requests or similar..?

Comment: Check out NW.js it's a platform which enables calls directly to Node apis from html.

Comment: Well looks like it's using web socket connection... it's no magic ;)

Comment: @SijoPGeorge If this helped you, mark it as the correct answer.